# how to select the last value in a irregular data frame

Tags: python, analysis

I have a very big data frame with the orders for some products with a reference. This reference has periodical updates, so for the same product there are a lot of rows in the dataframe. I want to choose the last update for each reference, but i dont know why.

For a reference, for example there are 10 updates, for another, 34, so there is not a patron...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it should be something like -

```
df.sort_values("update_date",ascending=False).groupby("reference").first()
```

You first sort the data frame by the update_date is descending order and then group it by `reference` and for each reference choose the first record

Answer (score 0):

you can use func iget like this :

df['column'].iget(-1);

or
df.iloc[-1:]